# Does the ArcGIS Online "Spatial Analysis Service" require data to be hosted on ArcGIS.com?

Tags: geoprocessing, arcgis-online

I'm exploring the new-ish ArcGIS.com [Spatial Analysis Service](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/rest/analysis/).

> The Spatial Analysis service contains a number of tasks that allow you
>   to perform common spatial analyses **on your hosted data**.

I'd like to use it to aggregate attributes from a variety of sources against a target layer - similar to the [Union](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=union_%28analysis%29) geoProcessing command.

Does "your hosted data" mean that the spatial analysis service requires all data sources to be stored in ArcGIS.com?

The documentation also states:

> These tools allow end-users to easily perform analysis against layers
>   hosted in Online as well as **other layers they have access to**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like both hosted and accessible (layers with proper write privileges given to you) can use spatial analysis service (have not tried but looking at the statements and website on it)